# Why is istream::get not returning the expected value?

Tags: c++

**Question:**
When I run my code on several files to extract the contents, on around 20% of the files the first iteration sets both `a` and `b` to `255` (each bit is a 1), and the program exits immediately because this should not have happened. What error could be causing this?

**Code:**

```
    ifstream file(file_name);
    ofstream output(outfile_name);
    vector<string> dictionary; //these are all properly initialized earlier
    unsigned char a, b;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        a = file.get();
        if(!file.eof()) b = file.get();
        else break;
        int id = b + 256*a;
        if(id < 0 || id > dictionary.size()) //this shouldn't happen
        {
            cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << id <<  endl;
            break;
        }
        output << dictionary[id] << ' ';
    }
```

**Background:** I had several large files, and decided to iterate through all of them and generate a dictionary. Using the ordered dictionary, I assigned each word a unique ID (of two `unsigned char`s, `a` and `b`). I then replaced all words with their unique IDs, which is what `file` now is, a long sequence of `unsigned char`s, two for each word. Unfortunately converting from the IDs back to the words does not seem to be working properly. Why are `a` and `b` being set to `255` when traversing certain files?

Comment: [For reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of that.

Comment: Also always check that the file actually opened.

Comment: It does, I just didn't include that portion of the code.

Comment: Did you look at your input files with a hex editor?  Perhaps the data there isn't what you think.